# CSS slideshow transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a CSS slideshow with dynamically imported images, but now am having trouble adding a transition. I want the images to slide when I click the next or previous buttons, but can't find a solution to this issue. Here is a snippet of my current code:

```js
$("#Next").click(function(){
 $("#Slider").append($("#Slider img:first-of-type"));
});

$("#Prev").click(function(){
 $("#Slider").prepend($("#Slider img:last-of-type"));
});
```

```css
html{
 align-items: center;
 background-color: #31353D;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

#Wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#Slideshow{
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

#Slider{
 border: 5px solid #1C1D21;
 height: 568px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 1024px;
}

#Slider img{
 height: 568px;
 width: 1024px;
 transition: all 1s;
}

#Arrows{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 height: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 1024px;
}

#Arrows i{
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
 color: #1C1D21;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 30px;
 padding: 15px;

 transition: background-color .5s, color .5s;
}

#Arrows i:first-of-type{
 padding-right: 20px;
}

#Arrows i:last-of-type{
 padding-left: 20px;
}

#Arrows i:hover{
 background-color: rgba(28,29,33, .75);
 color: #EEEFF7;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-h20CPZ0QyXlBuAw7A+KluUYx/3pK+c7lYEpqLTlxjYQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slideshow.css">
    <script src="js/display.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="Wrapper">
     <div id="Slideshow">
      <div id="Slider">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=1">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=2">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=3">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=4">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=5">
      </div>
      <div id="Arrows">
       <i id="Prev" class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <i id="Next" class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
      <script src="js/slideshow.js"></script>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to add a transition to the next image when you click the next or prev buttons?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009723/css-js-image-slide-out-animation

Comment: Not really, I just want a normal slideshow that slides the images left or right the depending on if you click next or previous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not enough by just using CSS to achieve what you want. I see that you're also using JS to achieve the sliding animation, so I've given myself a choice of also using JS to solve the problem. The idea is to perform translation using `transform: translate(...)` conjoined with `transition` to do the sliding animation. We will be performing the translation to the images inside the slideshow.

Here's an example showing how it can be done. I've opted to use vanilla JS instead of jQuery as it seems like you don't necessitate jQuery.

*Although unrelated, I've fixed your HTML so that it's less nested and I've also moved your arrows div so that it's easier to adjust using CSS.*

```js
const next = document.querySelector('#Next')
const prev = document.querySelector('#Prev')
const slider = document.querySelector('#Slider')

let images = slider.querySelectorAll('img')
let currentImageIndex = 0
let maxImageIndex = images.length - 1

next.addEventListener('click', e => {
  updateCurrentImageIndex(1)
  slideImage()
})

prev.addEventListener('click', e => {
  updateCurrentImageIndex(-1)
  slideImage()
})

function updateCurrentImageIndex(value) {
  currentImageIndex += value
  if (currentImageIndex < 0) currentImageIndex = maxImageIndex
  else if (currentImageIndex > maxImageIndex) currentImageIndex = 0
}

function slideImage() {
  images.forEach(image => {
    image.style.transform = `translateX(${-100 * currentImageIndex}%)`
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #31353D;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#Slider {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #1C1D21;
  overflow: hidden;  
}

#Slider img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;  
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#Arrows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#Arrows i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
  color: #1C1D21;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: background-color .5s, color .5s;
}

#Arrows i:last-of-type {
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
}

#Arrows i:hover {
  background-color: rgba(28, 29, 33, .75);
  color: #EEEFF7;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-h20CPZ0QyXlBuAw7A+KluUYx/3pK+c7lYEpqLTlxjYQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slideshow.css">
  <script src="js/display.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Slider">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=1">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=3">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=4">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1024x568.jpg?text=5">
      <div id="Arrows">
        <i id="Prev" class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i id="Next" class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/slideshow.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```